# box-shadow in below of overlap element and not float text near image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I'm coding In order to finally achieve this result(https://pasteboard.co/H2BwMM7.jpg).
The HTML code is this:

```
<body>

<div>
<div class="box">
     <span class="imgBox"><img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="img-rounded" width="150px" height="150px"/></span>
     <div class="text">
     <h1>mamad</h1>
     <h4>author</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well wellBox" role="alert">

    <div class="text-body">
  <h4>Well done!</h4>

  <p>Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This example text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how spacing within an alert works with this kind of content.
  Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice and tidy.</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and the css is this:

```
<style>
div.box {
float:right;
top:25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:3;
right:0;
display:inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;

}
h1{
margin-top:0px
}
div.box:after,div.wellBox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;

  top: -20px;

}
div.box:after{
  right: -10px;
}
div.wellBox:after{
left: -10px;
}
div.box:before,div.wellBox:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;

  top: -10px;

}
div.box:before{
right: -20px;
}
div.wellBox:before{
left: -20px;
}
.wellBox{
box-shadow: -10px 10px 8px #888888;
}
.imgBox{
box-shadow: -10px 10px 8px #888888;  z-index:1;    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
img{float:right;  z-index:2;}


.wellBox{
width:80%;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
top:146px;
text-align:right

}
.text{
float:right;
display:inline;
text-align:right;
margin-right:30px
}
h1,h4{

color:black}

</style>
```

The result that I finally got is this url(https://pasteboard.co/H2ByVvW.jpg).
In order to obtain the desired result, I need to:
1.put text of div to class "well" in Where is marked with a green line
2.box-shadow of image put below div to class "well".
3.in mobile size div to class "text" dont have Far away of div to class "text-body".

I tried a lot, but I did not get a good result that really pleases me... Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm.. I have a feeling that you won't be able to do this with a box-shadow given the layering.  A pseudo-element might work better utilising z-`index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this if you use the correct colors and a transparentized `box-shadow` instead of a solid color.

#### [Check out this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxmr8fu2/1/)

Specifically see lines `55` & `61`

Comment: thanks. Do you have any idea to put the text with class called "text-body" where it is specific to green line((https://pasteboard.co/H2BwMM7.jpg)?
Like the position in this (https://pasteboard.co/H2ByVvW.jpg).

Comment: Yes, you will need to make a few modifications, that I unfortunately don't have time to elaborate on. But look into using a `calc`-based width for your text-body. Since your image is 150px wide, you can do something like `width: calc(100% - 150px)`. You will, however, need to move the background color to your `well-body` and will need to adjust the name/title. Sorry I can't offer more detail right now, but I hope this helps!